# Powershell Error Trap for Get-ChildItem -Filter and Robocopy (ErrorAction)

Tags: powershell, robocopy, get-childitem, powershell-trap

I'm drafting a powershell script to manually backup some DC's. The backups need to be moved from one folder to another and I am using Get-ChildItem -Filter "Backup*" to select the backup files, then robocopy to move them.

It works but I would like to add in a trap and custom error message "Error Copying Local Backup from XX to SystemStateBackup" if the source or destination path is incorrect. I would also like to pipe any errors to a log file.

The original with no trap is

```
 Get-ChildItem f:\WindowsImageBackup\ITUPW-PRODDC7 -Filter "Backup*" -Name | ForEach-Object { 
 robocopy "f:\WindowsImageBackup\ITUPW-PRODDC7\$_" "f:\WindowsImageBackup\ITUPW-PRODDC7\SystemStateBackup\$_" /Z /S /MOVE /njh /njs /ndl /nc /ns /np /nfl}
```

The trap will work if I only use part of the code

```
Trap {"Error Copying Local Backup from XX to SystemStateBackup";Continue} Get-ChildItem f:\WindowsImageBackup\ITUPW-PRODDC7 -Filter "Backup*" -Name -ea "Stop"
```

But it won't work this way

```
Trap {"Error Copying Local Backup from XX to SystemStateBackup";Continue} Get-ChildItem f:\WindowsImageBackup\ITUPW-PRODDC7 -Filter "Backup*" -Name | ForEach-Object { 
robocopy "f:\WindowsImageBackup\ITUPW-PRODDC7\$_" "f:\WindowsImageBackup\ITUPW-PRODDC7\SystemStateBackup\$_" /Z /S /MOVE /njh /njs /ndl /nc /ns /np /nfl} -ea "Stop"
```

It results in the following powershell error

> > Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'F:\WindowsImageBackup\ITUPW-PRODDC' because it does not exist.
> >     At line:1 char:88
> >     + Trap {"Error Copying Local Backup from XX to SystemStateBackup";Continue} Get-ChildItem <<<<  f:\WindowsImageBackup\I
> >     TUPW-PRODDC -Filter "Backup*" -Name | ForEach-Object { robocopy "f:\WindowsImageBackup\ITUPW-PRODDC7\$*" "f:\WindowsIma
> >     geBackup\ITUPW-PRODDC7\SystemStateBackup\$*" /Z /S /MOVE /njh /njs /ndl /nc /ns /np /nfl} -ea "Stop"
> >         + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (F:\WindowsImageBackup\ITUPW-PRODDC:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoun
> >        dException
> >         + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for you time.

Amelia - A sys admin who drew the short straw

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using. You can tell by typing `$host`.

Comment: Have you tried dropping the -filter and just using Get-ChildItem "F:\WindowsImageBackup\ITUPW-PRODDC7\Backup*"

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the `-ea "Stop"` to the foreach rather than to the Get-ChildItem. Move it before the pipe `|`

For the robocopy, you might want to use `$?` or `$lastexitcode` (within the foreach-object) to see if it ran fine.

Comment: Thanks. I can get the trap working for Get-ChildItem without the robocopy. Could someone please advise how I could put this into a function so I can apply '-ea "Stop"' to both?